# CSS width and height property is not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to get my divs to cut the entire window evenly into four even squares.

I have the width and height property of each div set to `50vh` while in a container with `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap`.

But what is being displayed is four rectangular divs, not square divs at all.

I tried changing it to 50% but that did not help. Here is my code:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.square {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="square">Britt</div>
  <div class="square">JOn</div>
  <div class="square">Devin</div>
  <div class="square">Brevin</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [It does work](https://jsfiddle.net/rp3qsv9t/). What are you talking about?

Comment: If you want to divide the window into four even squares, that requires the window to be a square. Anytime you resize the window, and it is no longer a perfect square, the four boxes cannot remain squares, unless they no longer cover the entire window.

Comment: Could you let me know what is not working with the answer a gave, so I will be able to adjust and you to accept?

Comment: I decided to go a different route, but your example does work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.square {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  height: 50vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="square">Britt</div>
  <div class="square">JOn</div>
  <div class="square">Devin</div>
  <div class="square">Brevin</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in order to get square divs, you need to add

```
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
```

to your #container. You need to set the container as square first.